# Is there a way to check if a file is encrypted?

Tags: php

Is there a way to check if a file is encrypted?

Comment: What type of encryption are you looking for? Or if you're doing a blanket check, what type of files?

Comment: I am just checking text file ..if its encrypted or not

Comment: @user295189 Please update your question to reflect your needs.

Comment: no way to tell. a text file in latin, sanskrit or a dead language may appear encrypted to some.

Comment: @stillstanding You're wrong. There's no way to tell for sure, but you can determine if a text is likely to have be encrypted.

Comment: At a bare minimum, everything is ROT26 encrypted.

Comment: "no way to tell for sure" - so you can't be sure. "likely" is never sure. end of story.

Comment: @stillstanding Do you use hashing algorithms? If you ever used `md5(password) == savedHashedPassword` then you should know that `very likely` is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming text file.*

You can measure character distribution. If characters appear in numbers close to each other (i.e. a small variance) then you most likely have an encrypted file.

Of course this can only be applied to large enough files. You can't tell if a file containing only "ABC" is encrypted or not.

*Assuming binary data.*

Similar to the above, but it's a little harder to explain.

Comment: a simple rot13 won't change the original statistical character distribution

Comment: @stillstanding A simple rot13 is not proper encryption.

Comment: I don't know how to formally define it in English, but all the secure/modern encryption algorithms have the property that the distribution of encrypted text is uniform. You can't really count a Caesar cipher that's been invented 2000 years ago as a cryptosystem.

Comment: Wikipedia - Encryption is the process of transforming information  (referred to as plaintext) using an algorithm  (called cipher) to make it unreadable to anyone except those possessing special knowledge. rot13() is a transformative function. That doesn't qualify as encryption?

Comment: @Alin Purcaru:Please refer the latest answer

Comment: That doesn't qualify as *secure* encryption because it can be broken with frequency analysis. Actually anything that does not have uniform distribution for the encrypted text can be broken with some form of frequency analysis.